# Exclude values above/below a threshold from auto-scaling in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have a series of datapoints like `[1,2,5,4, -50, 0,1,1,3,...]`, so they are in a rough range of values, and then there's a few that are way, way larger (or smaller). If I just plot them, the automatic scale produces a useless plot, since all the details are compressed beyond visibility.

I have a good idea of the rough range of the actual data, and

It's possible to set the scale manually, but then the limits have to be manually set for each plot, which is a lot of effort, or else waste a lot of screen space by setting overly loose once.

My current solution is setting values beyond the threshold to `nan`, using something like

```
nandata[data<threshold] = np.nan
```

Those values then get ignored by matplotlib while plotting. However, that approach has two disadvantages: First, I either have to screw around with my data and risk nasty side effects, or I have to make a copy each time, which isn't great for memory use of efficiency. Second, those values get completly dropped. But while I don't want them to hide details, I do want to be able to tell that there are outliers there. With proper scaling, I could just zoom out in interactive mode, or I could have a connecting line that goes off-screen.

Is there a way to apply the autoscale only to values inside a range?

Comment: Is your data in a pandas dataframe? Or numpy arrays?

Comment: It's numpy arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you’re looking for but you could apply the filtering at the plot step, plotting the filtered data but leaving the original data untouched and without making any extra copies. Then you can get the auto scaled x and y limits before plotting the outliers - after which you revert the x and y limits to their pre-outlier values. It should not be significantly more inefficient than a single plot. Something like this

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,10,25)
y = np.sin(x)
y[-1] = -200
cond = y > -25
plt.scatter(x[cond],y[cond])
xlim = plt.xlim()
ylim = plt.ylim()
plt.scatter(x[cond == False], y[cond == False])
plt.xlim(xlim)
plt.ylim(ylim)
plt.show()
```

Without the filtering this shows

[image]

and with the filtering it shows

[image]

but upon zooming out the outlier is visible again. I’m certain there’s a more elegant solution here but this might suffice for your purposes.

---

### Edit

To make this less cumbersome it can be wrapped in a convenience function as follows

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def scaledScatter(x, y, cond, **kwargs):
    plt.scatter(x[cond],y[cond], **kwargs)
    xlim = plt.xlim()
    ylim = plt.ylim()
    plt.scatter(x[cond == False], y[cond == False], **kwargs)
    plt.xlim(xlim)
    plt.ylim(ylim)

x = np.linspace(0,10,25)
y = np.sin(x)
y[-1] = -200
cond = y > -25
scaledScatter(x, y, cond, color = 'k', marker = '.')
plt.show()
```

Note that this formulation allows the usual keyword arguments for `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` to be passed in and propagates them appropriately.

Comment: That is an improvement in function, though it's also more cumbersome.
Couldn't you plot everything the second time around, so that connecting lines off-screen are kept (I use them as a marker that there are off-screen points here)?

Comment: @BurnNote The built in [`matplotlib.pyplot.autoscale`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.autoscale.html) does not have any arguments by which to filter the data included. Any 'lossless' filtering will be more cumbersome than 'lossy' filtering. This approach can easily be turned into a function which performs this scaling in a single call while preserving the matplotlib plotting control. I will add an example of this